# how to read/list 30 lines per page in a large text file report in Java?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, txt

I have a Java question that deals with reading the txt file and pulling data from it.

It's a bunch of used cars stored in a txt report file. They have several different lots that they sell from. The lots are identified by the 5 digit zip code followed by a zip code extension at the beginning of each record. They would like a report that lists all cars sold from all lots. This is what I come up with:

[image: The image needs to be 30 cars per page]

They would like the report to list 30 cars per page, on the report. Each page is to have headings and a page number. Like this:

[image: The report listed 30 cars per page with their headings and page #]

My question is how do I list 30 cars per page instead of all together (Each page 30 cars with headings and page #)?

Here's my source code:

```java
public class CustomerSale {

    // Details of reports
    private String zipCodeExtension;

    private int customerNumber;

    private String customerName;

    private int purchaseDate;

    private String make;

    private int purchasePrice;

    private int yearOfVehicle;

    private int satisfactionRating;



    // Create constructor argument

    public CustomerSale(String zipCodeExtension, int customerNumber, String customerName,
                        int purchaseDate, String make, int purchasePrice,
                        int yearOfVehicle, int satisfactionRating) {
        this.zipCodeExtension = zipCodeExtension;
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
        this.make = make;
        this.purchasePrice = purchasePrice;
        this.yearOfVehicle = yearOfVehicle;
        this.satisfactionRating = satisfactionRating;
    }


    // Create getters and setters

    public String getMake() {

        return make;

    }

    public void setMake(String make) {

        this.make = make;

    }


    public String getZipCodeExtension() {

        return zipCodeExtension;

    }

    public void setZipCodeExtension(String zipCodeExtension) {

        this.zipCodeExtension = zipCodeExtension;

    }

    public int getCustomerNumber() {

        return customerNumber;

    }

    public void setCustomerNumber(int customerNumber) {

        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;

    }

    public String getCustomerName() {

        return customerName;

    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {

        this.customerName = customerName;

    }

    public int getPurchaseDate() {

        return purchaseDate;

    }

    public void setPurchaseDate(int purchaseDate) {

        this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;

    }

    public double getPurchasePrice() {

        return purchasePrice;

    }

    public void setPurchasePrice(int purchasePrice) {

        this.purchasePrice = purchasePrice;

    }

    public int getYearOfVehicle() {

        return yearOfVehicle;

    }

    public void setYearOfVehicle(int yearOfVehicle) {

        this.yearOfVehicle = yearOfVehicle;

    }


    public int getSatisfactionRating() {

        return satisfactionRating;

    }

    public void setSatisfactionRating(int satisfactionRating) {

        this.satisfactionRating = satisfactionRating;

    }
}
```

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ABCUsedCars {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File carsInfo = new File("src/custsale.txt");
        Scanner carsScanner = new Scanner(carsInfo);

        System.out.println(
                "-------------------------------------------------ABC USED CARS----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(
                "-------------------------------------------------------PAGE 1-----------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.printf("%-19s%-15s%-21s%-15s%-20s%-17s%-12s%-20s\n", "|ZIP CODE-EXT|","|CUST No.|", "|CUSTOMER NAME|", "|DoP|",
                "|MAKE|", "|PRICE|", "|YEAR|", "|RATE|");
        System.out.println(
                "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        String format = "%-20s%-14s%-21s%-16s%-19s$%-17s%-14s%-20s\n";

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,#####");

        while (carsScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String zipCodeExtension = carsScanner.nextLine();
            int customerNumber = Integer.parseInt(carsScanner.nextLine());
            String customerName = carsScanner.nextLine();
            int purchaseDate = Integer.parseInt(carsScanner.nextLine());
            String make = carsScanner.nextLine();
            int purchasePrice = Integer.parseInt(carsScanner.nextLine());
            int yearOfVehicle = Integer.parseInt(carsScanner.nextLine());
            int satisfactionRating = Integer.parseInt(carsScanner.nextLine());
            CustomerSale custsale = new CustomerSale(zipCodeExtension, customerNumber, customerName,
                    purchaseDate, make, purchasePrice, yearOfVehicle, satisfactionRating);

            System.out.printf(format, custsale.getZipCodeExtension(), custsale.getCustomerNumber(),
                    custsale.getCustomerName(),custsale.getPurchaseDate(), custsale.getMake(),
                    df.format(custsale.getPurchasePrice()),custsale.getYearOfVehicle(),
                    custsale.getSatisfactionRating());
        }

        carsScanner.close();
    }
}
```

Here's text file report:

```
46410-1234
1001
ALBERT, CARL T.
08252001
FORD
0255000
1991
2
46307-1201
1003
ANDREWS, ROBERT
08262001
CHEVROLET
0700000
1958
0
46423-2311
1008
ANZIO, RAFELINO
09012001
CHEVROLET
0456050
1978
0
46424-0121
1010
ASHLEY, WILLIAM B.
09022001
PIERCE-ARROW
1240000
1932
2
46375-3110
1015
ATKINSON, MARK
08272001
STUDEBAKER
0050000
1958
1
46405-1291
1025
AVERY, ALFRED A.
08292001
HUDSON
0230000
1954
1
46301-1234
1031
BEZZMEK, JENNIFER
08272001
FORD
0455000
1995
2
46303-1201
1033
BLAKE, DONALD
08292001
FORD
0722050
1989
1
46413-2311
1041
BLONDELL, BONNIE
09042001
CHEVROLET
0356050
1988
1
46404-0121
1045
BONADIO, JAMES
09032001
PIERCE-ARROW
1150000
1935
2
46307-3110
1055
BUCKO, ONIEDA
08282001
STUDEBAKER
0245000
1964
1
46410-1291
1056
BYMANN, FREDRICK
08292001
FORD
0330000
1994
1
46342-1234
1061
CALBERT, RONALD
09052001
FORD
0355000
1993
2
46307-1211
1063
CHELSEA, MARTHA S.
08302001
DODGE BROS.
0350000
1935
0
46410-2311
1067
CLAFLIN, WAYNE R.
09012001
CHEVROLET
0456050
1990
2
46410-0121
1070
COLE, CHARLES C.
09022001
PIERCE-ARROW
1050000
1929
2
46305-3111
1075
COLEMAN, THOMAS
08272001
STUDEBAKER
0167050
1961
1
46410-1221
1076
COLWELL, RICHARD L.
08292001
HUDSON
0430000
1940
1
46414-1231
1080
COOPER, JOHNATHAN
09052001
FORD
1256000
1996
2
46307-1201
2002
COREY, SARAH D.
08272001
CHEVROLET
0650050
1994
0
46421-2311
2004
CRACKLIN, GOODMAN
09012001
CHEVROLET
1456050
1996
0
46323-0121
2011
CRAWFORD, TIMOTHY
09012001
PIERCE-ARROW
1040000
1931
2
46315-3110
2012
CURRIE, RAYMOND
08282001
STUDEBAKER
0150025
1956
1
46425-1291
2024
CYBORG, IZORE M.
09052001
HUDSON
0130000
1949
1
46410-1234
2031
DALTON, DAVID P.
08252001
FORD
0234000
1990
2
46307-1201
2043
DAVIES, RALPH O.
08262001
CHEVROLET
0333000
1989
0
46423-2311
2048
DENNICK, DONNA
09012001
CHEVROLET
0656025
1995
0
46424-0121
2050
DERBIN, DEANNA
09022001
PIERCE-ARROW
1640025
1937
2
46375-3110
2065
DONNEHUE, PHILLIP
09042001
STUDEBAKER
0054000
1966
1
46405-1291
2085
DOPPLER, RADAR O.
08302001
HUDSON
0311000
1951
1
46310-1234
2091
DUNLOP, RITA
08252001
FORD
1450045
1996
2
46303-1201
3003
DYKES, CYNTHIA
08262001
FORD
0410050
1987
1
46413-2311
3011
EATON, ESTER B.
09012001
CHEVROLET
1356050
1996
0
46404-0121
3015
EFFLEY, BAILY
09022001
PIERCE-ARROW
1446045
1933
2
46307-3110
3025
EGGERTON, AMANDA
08292001
STUDEBAKER
0335000
1965
1
46410-1291
3026
EPPLEY, DAVID
08282001
FORD
0414000
1995
1
46342-1234
3031
ERKLE, ROSA
09032001
FORD
0355020
1993
2
46307-1211
3043
FARNSWORTH, WESLEY
09052001
DODGE BROS.
1150000
1996
0
46410-2311
3047
FLANNERY, JAMES
09012001
CHEVROLET
0450050
1992
0
46410-0121
3050
FOREMAN, OTTO J.
09022001
PIERCE-ARROW
0940000
1927
2
46305-3111
3055
FOWLER, KATHLEEN
08272001
STUDEBAKER
0267050
1964
1
46410-1221
3056
FURNACE, DAVID
08292001
HUDSON
0530000
1948
1
46414-1231
3061
GALLAGHER, CLARENCE
0904200
1FORD
1006000
1992
2
46307-1201
3062
GENNERRO, TONY S.
08302001
CHEVROLET
0320050
1989
0
46421-2311
3066
GOEBEL, NANCY K.
09022001
CHEVROLET
0643050
1990
0
46323-0121
3072
GUNTHER, FREDERICK
09032001
PIERCE-ARROW
1260000
1930
2
46315-3110
3080
HAINES, MARSHALL
08292001
STUDEBAKER
02500251
959
1
46425-1291
3094
HANCOCK, JONATHON
09032001
HUDSON
0330000
1953
1
46423-2311
3098
HARTNETT, ROBERTO
09052001
CHEVROLET
0326040
1988
0
46424-0121
4005
HENNING, SONIA
09052001
PIERCE-ARROW
1305000
1928
2
46375-3110
4009
HORNSBY, ROGERS
08252001
STUDEBAKER
0167500
1962
1
46405-1291
4012
HYATT, JANET F.
08302001
HUDSON
0155000
1951
1
46301-1234
4021
IDZIOR, RAYMOND
09012001
FORD
1460000
1996
2
46303-1201
4022
JENNINGS, WILLIAM
08262001
FORD
0612040
1992
1
46410-2311
4024
JOHNSON, JACK
09032001
CHEVROLET
0256050
1985
0
46404-0121
4032
KULKA, ROBERT C.
09042001
PIERCE-ARROW
0970000
1934
2
46307-3110
4035
KURTZ, DONALD
08302001
STUDEBAKER
0345000
1966
1
46410-1291
4038
LEVANDOWSKI, JILL
08282001
DODGE BROS.
0430000
1988
1
46342-1234
4044
METZ, ARNOLD E.
09012001
FORD
1323000
1996
2
46307-1211
4046
NORRIS, CHARLES S.
09052001
CHEVROLET
0844000
1992
0
46410-2311
4047
NOWAKOWSKI, ALFRED
09012001
DODGE BROS.
0656050
1994
1
46410-0121
4053
O'BOYLE, NIEL
09032001
PIERCE-ARROW
1550000
1938
2
46305-3111
4056
O'BRIAN, PATRICK
08302001
STUDEBAKER
0347050
1962
1
46410-1221
4059
PATTERSON, LENNI R.
08292001
HUDSON
0250000
1946
1
46414-1231
4061
PERRY, SHAMUS
09052001
FORD
0895000
1994
2
46307-1201
4066
REED, ROBERT B.
08272001
CHEVROLET
0740050
1996
0
46421-2311
4067
RODRIGUEZ, ALONZO
09052001
DODGE BROS.
1050050
1995
0
46323-0121
4073
SANCHEZ, HENRY
09012001
PIERCE-ARROW
0830000
1925
2
46315-3110
4081
SWARTZ, HECTOR
08282001
STUDEBAKER
0075025
1954
1
46301-1234
4084
TORREZ, MARTIN
0827200
1FORD
0565000
1994
2
46303-1201
4090
TUTTLE, MARK
08292001
FORD
0710050
1996
1
46413-2311
4094
WARNER, JACK
09042001
CHEVROLET
0856050
1996
0
46404-0121
4115
YACKLEY, YOURTO
09042001
PIERCE-ARROW
1000000
1930
2
```

Comment: Just count the number of cars written to your output and whenever `count % 30 == 0` you write the page header. The page number would then be `count / 30 + 1`. (Note: update the counter _after_ writing a car so when you're about to write car no. 31 the counter will be at 30 and thus you've hit the start of a new page and page number will be 30/30 + 1 = 2.)

Comment: @Thomas This is sounds cool. Would you mind putting your solution into the above while loop so I can visualize your logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already stated in my comment you'd need to count the cars you've already processed and print new page headers when you've hit a multiple of 30 cars.

First I'd suggest moving your header print statements to a separate method, e.g. `printPageHeader(int pageNumber)`. Then change your loop like this:

```
final int pageSize = 30;
int carCounter = 0;

while (carsScanner.hasNextLine()) {
  if( carCounter % pageSize  == 0 ) {
    printPageHeader( carCounter / pageSize + 1 );
  }
  
  //read car lines here

  //print your car
  System.out.printf(format, ... );

  //count the car
  carCounter++;
}
```

Comment: This worked well and I did the same thing you told me but there one little issue that I couldn't solve it which is updating page # when I printed out the report. This is what I have done so far if you have a Repl account: https://replit.com/join/xujzmlox-sadaad

Comment: Never mind, I fixed my issue by doing "PAGE " + i inside of printPageHeader method. Hats off man, you've been very helpful. Appreciated. If you don't mind I have one more question and see if you could help me out one more time.

Comment: @MoFatah you're welcome. As for the other question: just post a new one and if I have time I'll have a look - but others probably will do so as well :) - Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem :)

Comment: @MoFatah one suggestion on your header though: don't use `"...PAGE " + i + "---..."` but use `String.format()` or `System.out.printf()` as you're doing with other lines. This would allow you to format the number easily so that it adds some spaces (or leading zeros if you want) to keep lenghts consistent. With `"PAGE " + i` you'd get more characters depending on the page number (i.e. "10" vs. "9") and thus the rest of that line might be off.

Comment: @MoFatah the answer you got there is fine already. You just might to want `Collections.sort(...)` with the comparator instead of the stream but both versions should work for you.